# How to enroll Apple Develop Programe

Tags: ios, user-enrollment, apple-developer-enterprise

I’ve been trying to pay for Apple Developer Program enrollment  still no luck. As well as I got from a small talk with the customer support – Apple never got my money. So it seems like my payment authorization fails all the time. But I don’t know what’s really going on.

Thanks

Comment: We cannot help you with that. Make sure you are on the genuine Apple page when you pay and if it does not work, you will need to work it out with your bank and the Apple support.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is nothing we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

Oye it's a big hassle, I had the same problem recently. Try to call them and initiate a manual order and keep emailing them. Apple gets very sloppy processing the Apple Developers Account so you need to keep reminding them.

Comment: yeah, I called them, but they still answered unclear, with no specific solution